# Installing SUPEE 6285, error message still present in Admin area

Tags: security, patches

I made sure to remove 5994 and the old 6285 patch as can be seen in the following:

```
user@domain.com [~/public_html]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1-2015-05-15-04-34-46.sh -R
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

user@domain.com [~/public_html]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-10-08-10-09.sh -R
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

user@domain.com [~/public_html]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh -R
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

I then installed SUPEE-5994 and 6285 version 2:

```
user@domain.com [~/public_html]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1-2015-05-15-04-34-46.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

user@domain.com [~/public_html]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

I then deleted the content of /var/cache, /var/session and /var/tmp, however when I log into the Magento admin panel I am still getting the following popup message:

```
July 7, 2015: New Magento Security Patch (SUPEE-6285) – Install Immediately
```

I had no errors during the patch installations and Google doesn't seem to have any information on this. Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages in the backend are an RSS feed, created by magento (and everyone else which hooks into this) and shown by `Mage_AdminNotification`

If you have done everything you can mark it as read.

Comment: Oh, so that would be it. Thank you for the information. :)

Comment: Upvoted your comment since I didn't have enough reputation to do this when I initially asked the question.